# Syntax error in 'drop table' or 'drop index' in ssis package

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

I am deleting and recreating excel file using ssis. I used ExecuteSQLTask and write sqlstatement

```
drop table 'Employee'
go
CREATE TABLE `Employee` (
`BusinessEntityID` INT,
`JobTitle` NVARCHAR(50),
`BirthDate` DATE,
`MaritalStatus` NVARCHAR(1),
`Gender` NVARCHAR(1),
`HireDate` DATE
)
```

but when i am executing the package then i am getting the following error :

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "drop table 'Employee'
>   " failed with the following error: "Syntax error in DROP TABLE or DROP INDEX.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: the backticks are used in mysql, not SQL Server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove the character ` and try

```
drop table [Employee]
go

CREATE TABLE [Employee] 
(
[BusinessEntityID] INT,
[JobTitle] NVARCHAR(50),
[BirthDate] DATE,
[MaritalStatus] NVARCHAR(1),
[Gender] NVARCHAR(1),
[HireDate] DATE
)
```